# questions about Wronskians.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u_1, \ldots, u_n, u, v$ be functions. If $W(u, u_1, \ldots, u_n)=W(v, u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, is $u=v$? Here $W(u_1, u_2, u_3)$ for example is defined by 
$$
\pmatrix{ u_1& u_1'& u_1''\\ u_2& u_2'& u_2''\\u_3& u_3'& u_3''}.
$$

Comment: Isn't the Wronskian the **determinant** of that matrix?

Comment: I don't think so (assuming you're talking about the determinants of those matrices). If all $u_i$ are $0$, then this obviously false, othertwise, pick $u_{i_0}$ a non zero element  we have the $W(u+u_{i_0}, u_1, \ldots u_n) = W(u, u_1, \ldots u_n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Here's a counter-example:
$$W(2x+1, x) = \left| \begin{matrix} 2x+1 & 2 \\ x & 1 \end{matrix} \right| = 
2x + 1 - 2x = 1,$$ and
$$W(x+1, x) = \left| \begin{matrix} x+1 & 1 \\ x & 1 \end{matrix} \right| = 
x + 1 - x = 1.$$ But $2x+1 \neq x+1.$

At least for $n =1$, $W(u,u_1) = W(v,u_1) \Rightarrow u_1' (u-v)= u_1 ({u'-v'}),$ but not necessarily $u = v.$